# How to style GWT Editor errors

Tags: java, gwt, cssresource, gwt-editors

I am using the GWT 2.4 Editor framework. I have everything working with errors displaying, but I am not sure how to style the errors! It looks like the styles are part of a CssResource as they are obfuscated. Anyone know how to go about styling these?

The errors I am wanting to style are the ones automatically added by the [ValueBoxEditorDecorator#showErrors](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/ui/client/ValueBoxEditorDecorator.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValueBoxEditorDecorator` is actually a bit "half-baked". You'd better copy/paste it to make your own.

Comment: Eh, I was afraid of that... Thanks for confirming.